# Monitoring office internet connection for drop outs in Ruby

Tags: ruby, tcp, connection, monitor

I am looking for a simple way to monitor our office internet connection for drop outs. A secondary pipe dream is to also monitor for other 'dodgy' behaviour - packet loss, jitter etc. But the primary goal is to watch for dropped connections. Pinging Google every second is great to keep an eye on latency but we have had a few temporary blips which have caused hell with a few streaming services but have not affected connection latency. The IT department also sometimes decide to block outgoing ICMP traffic which doesn't help with the humble ping tool's efforts.

If this is not something available already via an open source, freeware or commercial tool, ideally I would like to be able to come up with something in Ruby (or, if forced, .NET) which will open a 'long' TCP connection to an arbitrary web server on port 80 (i.e. I don't want to have to write something keeping a socket open on a hosted server) and have the program detect and alert the guys in the office if the connection drops out in a "bad" way. With my attempts using Ruby Socket (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html) I've had trouble extracting an accurate error code here; ideally I want to isolate actual network connectivity issues from the usual connection timeouts. On a timeout, I'll want to restart the connection silently, but on a real drop out, I'll flash something big and obvious up on screen to alert the guys in the office.

I've spent most of the day googling for examples of this kind of monitoring and trying to hack something together but it seems that it is not a common request. 99% of results are forum posts ending with me being authoritatively informed that speedtest.net will do everything I need. My own attempts have all proven futile - no matter which way I've tried, whenever I seem to be getting somewhere even the most basic drop out test (unplugging the network cable from my laptop!) fails to be detected.

- Is this something trivial, and if so could anyone point me in the right direction please? Or am I in for a world of pain? (This has been my general experience whenever I've tried to do anything with network programming in the past...)
- Alternatively is there anything pre-written (free, commericial, open source all fine) which will do just this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Smokeping might do what you want.  Nagios might as well.

http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/

http://www.nagios.org/